# Friendly URL adding to my links on the nav bar menu... creating issues

Tags: php

Website is PHP/mySQL. Some of the pages (inventory) have friendly URLs. Great.

The problem is when on these profile pages (those with friendly URLs), it is also adding that friendly URL in front of the links of the top nav bar (aka menu drop down).

So instead of faq.php ... now the link is productA/faq.php which of course breaks the links.

It is not doing it in the footer though, just the header links.

We have looked everywhere and admit defeat!

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing that we have no code to look at, I'll just have to throw out a wild (yet relevant) guess - you're using relative links in the header.

For example, instead of having `<a hreF="/faq.php">FAQ</a>` in the menu, you have `<a href="faq.php">FAQ</a>` or `<a href="./faq.php">FAQ</a>`, causing it to put the current directory structure before the file.

Comment: Great suggestion but we already checked. "faq.php" Could the database be adding the friendly URL?

Comment: Well, that's your issue. If it's just "faq.php", then it's "wrong". The thing you want here is the "/faq.php" to keep the file at the root. :)

Comment: You are a GENIUS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! It works. Thank you so very much. Lots of blessing to you.

Comment: No problem - don't forget to accept the answer (click the tick below the "score"). :)